# spark standalone cluster - set (custom) dependencies path?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Currently I am running a python script of spark streaming on a spark cluster. The script A imports a function from a self-defined script B, and the script B has dependent files. For example, the function searches whether a word exists in a dictionary, therefore the program needs to read a dictionary first. Also, scriptB utilises multiple packages such as Tensorflow, Keras and so on...

Therefore, zipping all dependencies and sending them over the network seems inefficient.

I wonder if there's a way to set the path for 1.python interpreter, 2.library 3.dependent files for the workers (slave nodes)??

Comment: I have found a dirty solution with the following step with the help from @RyanW: 1. point at my python interpretrer in the anaconda environment (where I installed all 3rd party dependencies). 2. add the "script B" in the anaconda environment too. / or you can send the script with --py-files (more efficient if you need to change your own modules frequently). 3. in script B set the absolute paths to your dependent files in the worker. In this case it's better to have the same paths to files and packages in all workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dependencies aren't going to change and you have the ability to easily install things on your cluster then you can just install the required files onto each worker.  The easiest way to do this an keep track of your dependencies is to create a venv from a requirements.txt file on each worker.  Then you can just point Spark at the the python interpret in your venv and all of your dependencies will be available.

To point spark at a specific interpreter, either:

A) Set **--conf 'spark.pyspark.python=/some/path/to/python'** in your spark-submit call, or

B) In **$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh** add this line

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/some/path/to/python
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just figured out how to set the interpreter (in my anaconda environment), but what about self-defined modules? Do I have to put those modules and the dependent files in something/like/path/to/anaconda/python/site-packages?

Comment: I usually install any 3rd party libraries into the venv on each worker using pip or conda install, and then package my own code into an egg file and distribute that with --py-files.  Usually my the dependencies don't change very often so you don't need to go update each machine, but your own code you will want to easily be able to deploy the latest updates.